# login_required decorator on a class based view in django

Tags: python, django, decorator, attributeerror, login-required

I have a working class based view. But when adding @login_required I get the error:

*AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'*

Something is happening to the ResultListView here:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ResultListView


urlpatterns = [
    path('meetings/', ResultListView.as_view(), name='meetings'),
]
```

My views.py:

```
@login_required
class ResultListView(ListView):
    template_name = ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Result.objects.filter(rider__user=self.request.user)
```

Which is all working fine until I put the decorator in. Very confused now, I don't see why *ResultListView* should loose its attributes when sending it through the decorator.

Comment: You can [decorate the class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) using `method_decorator`. However I prefer using `LoginRequiredMixin` as Willem suggests.

Answer (score 18):

The `@login_required` decorator only decorates functions, not classes, you can make use of a mixin, or decorate the function that is the result of the `.as_view()` call.

## Option 1: Using the `LoginRequiredMixin`

You can make use of the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) that you need to put *before* the `ListView` in the parent classes:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ResultListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = …

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Result.objects.filter(rider__user=self.request.user)
```

## Option 2: decorate the `.as_view()` result

An alternative is to decorate the outcome of the `.as_view`, which is indeed a function:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ResultListView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    path('meetings/', login_required(ResultListView.as_view()), name='meetings'),
]
```

Comment: Aha I see, yes that makes sense! Thanks for the quick and accurate reply!

Comment: Which is the better method?

Comment: @ByteInsight: I would advise using the mixin, since you can also combine it into other mixins and views you subclass. So once you mix it in a view, all subclasses of that view will require to login as well.

Comment: The main difference between LoginRequiredMixin and @ login_required is that LoginRequiredMixin is a mixin, while @ login_required is a decorator.

LoginRequiredMixin is an abstract class that can be inherited by a view class. When a view inherits from LoginRequiredMixin, Django checks that the user making the request is authenticated.

@ login_required is a decorator that can be used to decorate a view function.

Class vs View