# Even though its a class why is AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Tags: django, django-views

even though its a calss based func why is this attribute error popping up when i use login_required

**error Message**

```
path('active/<int:pk>', UpdateActiveStatus.as_view(), name="activeStatus"),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/admin/')
class UpdateActiveStatus(UpdateView):
    model = Timeline
    form_class = UpdateActiveStatus
    template_name = 'timeline.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('timeline')
```

Comment: Your question has already been answered, see this link:‌ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60871630/login-required-decorator-on-a-class-based-view-in-django

Comment: You can't use Decorators above class  inherit  **LoginRequiredMixin** in your class

Comment: @AashishKumar: there are decorators that can decorate a class, `@login_required` is simply not one of these: it assumes that it is given a function and returns a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator): this decorator returns a function, but even using the function will not work: the decorator simply can not handle a class.

For class-based views, you use the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class UpdateActiveStatus(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = FutsalTimeline
    form_class = UpdateActiveStatus
    template_name = 'timeline.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('timeline')
    login_url = '/admin/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is generated for the **decorator**. Just change it like ->

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UpdateActiveStatus(UpdateView):
    model = FutsalTimeline
    form_class = UpdateActiveStatus
    template_name = 'timeline.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('timeline')
```

You can find the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro#s-decorating-the-class)

- But you should use the **Mixin classes**. With **Mixin class** It will look like

  ```
    from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
    class UpdateActiveStatus(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
        model = FutsalTimeline
        form_class = UpdateActiveStatus
        template_name = 'timeline.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('timeline')
  ```

You can find the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default#s-the-loginrequired-mixin)